# when running jasmine task in grunt, getting an error "glob pattern string required"

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine

I am trying to run jasmine test using grunt-contrib-jasmine 
Below is my Gruntfile.js code

```
     module.exports = function(grunt) {
      grunt.initConfig({
        jasmine : {
          // Your project's source files
          src : 'src/**/*.js',
          // Your Jasmine spec files
          specs : 'specs/**/*spec.js',
          // Your spec helper files
          helpers : 'specs/helpers/*.js'
        }
      });

      // Register tasks.
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');

  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', 'jasmine');
};
```

Then I tried running "grunt jasmine" command from command prompt. It gives me an error like below
[image]

Comment: I'm getting this same issue. I don't have a solution yet, but it looks related to: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're describing was reported in [this grunt issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1461). It was then fixed in [this commit to grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine/commit/0eb7cf56029b59e4abb2fc52fd5148440bbde35e) on February 13 2016.

As of this writing, the [most recent release of grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine/releases) is [v1.0.0](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine/releases/tag/v1.0.0), released on January 26 2016. So, the fix didn't make it into the most recent release, which is what NPM pulls when you do an install.

You can get around this by bypassing the NPM repository and going straight to GitHub for a prerelease version of `grunt-contrib-jasmine`. You do this by changing your `package.json` to read:

```
"dependencies: {
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine#1e78d891704fa13fe7c7abf4cabf43cefacafcaf"
}
```

(The commit SHA in the URL just happens to be the [most recent one at the time of this writing](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine/commit/1e78d891704fa13fe7c7abf4cabf43cefacafcaf); feel free to replace it with a later one if you like.)

Ideally, this solution will become obsolete, when `grunt-contrib-jasmine` releases v1.0.1 (or higher) with the fix commit. Today though, this is what fixed the problem for me.